# Fill blocks when someone dies in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I am playing with my friend. For a few days, we have been working in a PVP arena. I also decided that I would use commands to do so. I would have a wall to separate the two players and when they click the start button, it removes the wall. So, I want to replace the wall when someone dies so the other person doesn't get unfair hits before the other person is ready. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You Need To Know

How chain command blocks work.

## What

At spawn, have a pressure plate. Have each team tagged so we can identify them! I will use tags “blue” and “red”. When this pressure plate is pressed, have it run the commands:

```
/fill 7 2 0 7 10 10 brick
```

Make a brick wall from 7, 2, 9 to 7, 10, 10.
Now an always active chain:

```
/tp @p[r=10,tag=red] 4 5 5
```

If red died, teleport them to where they need to go (I used 4, 5, 5). Do nothing if a blue player.
Then another always active chain:

```
/tp @p[r=10,tag=blue] 10 5 5
```

Do the same for blue, let’s say blue needs to go to 10, 5, 5. Then, this is optional, but another always active chain:

```
/to @p[r=10] 30 20 25
```

If somehow someone without an assigned team spawns, let’s put them at 30, 20, 25. This could be a spectator area, lobby, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much you are the best

Comment: That helped so much

Comment: Just one thing. I don't know how to make teams

Comment: @ArjunRawat you can tag people with `/tag` command, you can just google it for more help if you need it